# mongodb query about listing one field as an array with all collections in detailed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Assume I have db structure as;

```
[   
    {name: "alex" , age: 21, school: "x university" },
    {name: "felix" , age: 24, school: "y university" },
    {name: "tom" , age: 43, school: "z university" }
]
```

I want to write a query to get the details of the collection plus the array of the names. I mean as a result of the query I expect to get;

```
details:[   
    {name: "alex" , age: 21, school: "x university" },
    {name: "felix" , age: 24, school: "y university" },
    {name: "tom" , age: 43, school: "z university" }
],

names: ["alex", "felix", "tom"]
```

To able to get the names as an array I wrote,

```
db.colletion.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: "", names: {$addToSet : "$name"}}}
])
```

But this just prints the names as;

```
{ "_id" : "", "names" : [ "alex", "felix", "tom"] }
```

In grouping I can project fields something like,

```
db.colletion.aggregate([
    {$group: {age: {$first: "$age"}, _id: "", names: {$addToSet : "$name"}}}
])
```

But this db is just an example, I have dynamic fields that I don't know in advanced. So how can I build this query?

Comment: Do not keep trying to do what you are doing. This is stuffing the entire contents of the collection into a single document, which will surely break the BSON limit. If you just want the unique values of "name". Simply use `db.collection.distinct("name")`. Which will return exactly just that. But don't ask for the documents as well.

Comment: The completely useless statement is of course `db.collection.aggregate({ "$group": { "_id": null, "details": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }, "names": { "$addToSet": "$name" } })`. But I suspect you actually want "facets" for a larger result set to page data on. Like I said, this will blow up the BSON limit. And facets ( for which you can even use `$facet` ) should be run in a separate operation to the actual dataset returned.